# How to check a user's phone number without using third-party services

Tags: android, ios, react-native, validation

I need to check a user's phone number who register on my app.
I wanted to use 'Facebook Account Kit' to do that, but recently Facebook deprecated 'Account Kit'.

Is there a way to check a user's phone number for free without going through third party services or something like 'Facebook Account Kit' ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to check? If the telephone number exists? If the number has the correct format?

Comment: I want to check if the number exists by sending a sms to the user's phone or something else like that. Facebook account kit was free so it was a good for my budget, but now it is deprecated

Answer (score -1):

I recommend [libphonenumber](https://github.com/google/libphonenumber) by Google. The Java version is optimized for running on smartphones, and is used by the Android framework since 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich).